# Remove occurences of small words within a string

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to remove a specific word from a string. I can't do a simple global string replace for "the" to empty string as "the" could be part of a word in the string.

```
word: "the"
string: "the_ad_an_feta_cfr_era_the_iop_the"
output: "ad_an_feta_cfr_era_iop"
```

The word "the" could be at the beginning, several times in the middle or at the end of the string so I have to take into account the separator and beginning/end of string.

Could I handle all this with one regex or should I resort to looping, but how do I specify the multiple patterns in sed?

```
sed 's/the//g' <<< "the_ad_feta_cfr_era_the_iop_the"
```

Then how would I do it if I had several words I wanted to remove from the same string? Instead of only "the" also remove "is", "an". 
Can all this be one in regex without looping?

```
word: "the", "an", "is"
input: "the_ad_an_feta_cfr_era_the_iop_the"
output: "ad_feta_cfr_era_iop"
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this `sed`:

```
$ string='the_ad_an_feta_cfr_era_the_iop_the'
$ sed -E -e ':a' -e 's/(^|_)(the|an|is|feta)(_|$)/\1/g;ta' -e 's/_$//' <<< "$string"
ad_cfr_era_iop
```

Note that the behavior of `sed` differs between Unix variants. Your `sed` seems to require newlines after labels (or multiple `-e` options). Further reading:

- [BSD/macOS Sed vs. GNU Sed vs. the POSIX Sed specification](http://www.riptutorial.com/sed/topic/9436/bsd-macos-sed-vs--gnu-sed-vs--the-posix-sed-specification)
- [Differences between sed on Mac OSX and other “standard” sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed)

---

Version without labels which is essentially the same as [@Cyrus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52089352/6176817) but supports "items" with spaces:

```
$ string='the_ad_an_feta_cfr_era_the cfr_the_iop_the'
$ sed -E -e 's/_/__/g;s/(^|_)(the|an|is|feta)(_|$)//g;s/_+/_/g;s/^_//;s/_$//' <<< "$string"
ad_cfr_era_the cfr_iop
```